# generating boxes from octomap::octree error

Tags: ros, octomap, fcl, boost, octree

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the fcl where I have an octree and I want to generate boxes from an octree function
I used the following code:

```
    octomap::OcTree* st_tree = new octomap::OcTree(0.1);
    octomap::Pointcloud st_cld;
    // I fill the tree
    for(int i = 0;i<msg.points.size();i++){
        point3d endpoint((float) msg.points[i].x,(float) msg.points[i].y,(float) msg.points[i].z);
        st_cld.push_back(endpoint);
    }
    point3d origin(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    st_tree->insertPointCloud(st_cld,origin);
    st_tree->updateInnerOccupancy();
    st_tree->writeBinary("static_occ.bt");
   std::vector<CollisionObject*> boxes;
   generateBoxesFromOctomap(boxes, *st_tree);
```

The function is defined as the following:

```
 void generateBoxesFromOctomap(std::vector<CollisionObject*>& boxes, octomap::OcTree& tree)
    {

    std::vector<boost::array<FCL_REAL, 6> > boxes_ = tree.toBoxes();
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < boxes_.size(); ++i)
    {
        FCL_REAL x = boxes_[i][0];
        FCL_REAL y = boxes_[i][1];
        FCL_REAL z = boxes_[i][2];
        FCL_REAL size = boxes_[i][3];
        FCL_REAL cost = boxes_[i][4];
        FCL_REAL threshold = boxes_[i][5];
        Box* box = new Box(size, size, size);

        box->cost_density = cost;
        box->threshold_occupied = threshold;
        CollisionObject* obj = new CollisionObject(boost::shared_ptr<CollisionGeometry>(box), Transform3f(Vec3f(x, y, z)));
        boxes.push_back(obj);
    }
    std::cout << "boxes size: " << boxes.size() << std::endl;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
     error: ‘class octomap::OcTree’ has no member named ‘toBoxes’
     std::vector<boost::array<FCL_REAL, 6> > boxes_ = tree.toBoxes();
```

But I included the all the required libraries??

How can I solve it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203338/generating-boxes-from-octomap::octree-error/) by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2015-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no function `toBoxes` defined in OctoMap, so that code won't work. Best refer to the [official OctoMap documentation](http://octomap.github.io/octomap/doc/).

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2015-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to convert your octomap::OcTree to fcl::OcTree (is the same class name that why you have the confusion).
by convert your  octomap::OcTree to std::shared_pointer.
After you have fcl::OcTree instance. you can do toBoxes.
You can look at [official FCL documentation](http://docs.ros.org/fuerte/api/fcl/html/classfcl_1_1OcTree.html).

---

Originally posted by [Tal](https://answers.ros.org/users/11486/tal/) with karma: 108 on 2016-11-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3